# What happens when I pass really high current through the gate of a thyristor?

Tags: thyristor

I have a thyristor that requires 120mA(from datasheet) gate current  for triggering. I'm giving DC to gate and AC is connected across anode and cathode.

Now, according to theory, with dc triggering the SCR should be on for the positive half cycle and open for the negative half cycle. Thus, if I connect an oscilloscope across anode and cathode, I see a negative half cycle sine wave.

Now if I keep increasing the gate current(above 120mA) , I see the negative peak of the (-ve)half cycle decreasing and at some current(~850 mA) the voltage across the thyristor becomes zero. Which mean the thyristor is conducting throughout the AC cycle.

Why isn't the thyristor blocking the negative half cycle of the AC?
What exactly is happening here internally?

EDIT:

[image: Proteus imange I drew for actual setup]

This is a diagram I drew for this question. My actual setup is physical but is exactly the same. The DC source is a current source in my lab. The AC is given from a variac. And the DSO probes are at anode and cathode of U2.

The thyristor used is not available internationally. (HTT90N600D) I have my doubts about the availability of the datasheet. I have it personally, but I can't upload it on here I guess.

In any case, what I really wanted to know was what happens to the gate(and neighboring junctions) of ANY thyristor when large current passes through.

Comment: Where do you think the gate current is going?

Comment: @Finbarr well, I'm applying the voltage between gate and cathode so the current must flow to the cathode(?)

Comment: In order to explain exactly what is happening internally it is necessary to know exactly what is happening externally. Draw a diagram including the supply voltage and frequency, the load impedance and the source impedance of the supply. It is also necessary to know the thyristor specifications.

Comment: re " ... I have it personally, but I can't upload it on here I guess. ..." -> why not? || Consider: I rev my car to 25000 RPM and it dies. I have the manufacturers spec sheet but I will not share it with you. Why does my engine die?

Comment: What is the max allowed gate current from the datasheet?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon because there's no option to upload pdf. I didn't say the device died. Also, if the engine dies because I revved it too much then the mechanic must offer some explanation such as a blown gasket or whatever. What is happening here within the layers of the thyristors

Comment: @Aaron no such value is given. Only gate trigger current is given as 120mA.